# AssemblyScript on NEAR: `/bin/sh: asb: command not found` when deploying Guest Book with yarn

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

When running the [GuestBook example](https://github.com/near-examples/guest-book) on NEAR using `yarn deploy` the following error is produced:

```
/bin/sh: asb: command not found
```

This appears to be happening to people using the [Figment Learn NEAR path](https://learn.figment.io/network-documentation/near) as well, based on [Discord conversations](https://near.chat).

Running

```
npm install asb
```

returns

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: assemblyscript@0.17.14
npm WARN node_modules/assemblyscript
npm WARN   assemblyscript@"^0.17.3" from near-sdk-core@2.2.4
npm WARN   node_modules/near-sdk-core
npm WARN     near-sdk-core@"^2.2.4" from near-sdk-as@2.2.4
npm WARN     node_modules/near-sdk-as
npm WARN   1 more (@as-pect/cli)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer assemblyscript@"^0.13.3" from visitor-as@0.3.2
npm WARN node_modules/visitor-as
npm WARN   visitor-as@"^0.3.2" from near-sdk-core@2.2.4
npm WARN   node_modules/near-sdk-core
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asb - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'asb@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Edit:
Many `yarn install` and `yarn update` commands later, the error seems to have migrated to a missing `asc` library:

```
$ asb
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'assemblyscript/cli/asc'
```

Comment: `asb` appears to be run from the `asbuild` npm module https://github.com/AssemblyScript/asbuild

Answer (score 4):

You are correct the `asb` command is short for `asbuild` (which is another alias command), which is a dependency of `near-sdk-as` and should be installed with `yarn` or `yarn install`.

`asc`, installed as `assemblyscript`, should also be present because it is a dependency of `near-sdk-as`. So it not being found is suspicious.  My guesses are:

1. You need to run `yarn` first to install everything.
2. Somehow `NODE_ENV` was set to be `"production"`, which then causes `yarn` to install only `dependencies` and not `devDependencies`.  To fix this unset it with `NODE_ENV=` or `export NODE_ENV=`. Then run `yarn` again.

My one complaint with `npm` and `yarn` is that you need to have an install step.  Rust's `cargo` installs dependencies as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by login first to running yarn.

step 1: run `near login` and connect your wallet (testnet or mainnet for instance)

step 2: run `yarn` to install all dependencies.

This should works... greetings!

Answer (score 0):

In my case too, I was constantly getting this error no matter what I did;

> asb: command not found

While I was just giving up hope, this command was my solution.

```
yarn add -D near-sdk-as
```